# Aleatorizar Random

Tags: java, android, random

En mi método tengo una variable Random:

```
   public Bitmap getBmp(int nunidades,boolean base){
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(ladoWidth * nunidades, ladoHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
    int nbase = 0;
    int nespacio = 0;
    if(base){
        if(baseinicial != null){
            canvas.drawBitmap(baseinicial,0,0,null);
            nbase = 1;
        }
        for(;nbase < nunidades;nbase++){
            canvas.drawBitmap(baserepeticion,nbase*ladoWidth,0,null);
        }
    }else {
        //adornos
        if(!type.equalsIgnoreCase("Columnas")){
            int random = rnd.nextInt(adornos.size());
            ObjetoAdorno obj = new ObjetoAdorno(adornos.get(random).getTiles());
            ObjetoAdorno objf = new ObjetoAdorno();
            objf.setAdornos(obj.getAdornos());
            int tile = obj.getnAdornos();
            Log.d(GLOBALES.TAG,"espacio="+nunidades);
            Log.d(GLOBALES.TAG,"random="+random);
            Log.d(GLOBALES.TAG,"tile="+tile);
            if(nunidades> tile){
                Log.d(GLOBALES.TAG,"hay espacio");
                for(;nespacio < nunidades;nespacio++){
                    baseadornos.add(baserepeticion);
                    if(tile > 1){
                        for(int i=0;i<tile;i++){
                            baseadornos.add(objf.getAdornos().get(i));
                        }
                    }else{
                        baseadornos.add(objf.getAdornos().get(0));
                    }
                }
            }else{
                Log.d(GLOBALES.TAG,"No hay espacio");
                for(;nespacio < nunidades;nespacio++){
                    baseadornos.add(baserepeticion);
                }
            }
        }else{
            for(;nbase < nunidades;nbase++){
                baseadornos.add(baserepeticion);
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i < nunidades;i++){
            canvas.drawBitmap(baseadornos.get(i),i*ladoWidth,0,null);
        }
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

El problema es que el valor del random es siempre el mismo

Comment: Que quieres exactamente, coger un valor aleatorio dentro del rango de `adornos.size()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comprueba el tamaño de tu coleccion `adornos`:

```
int random = rnd.nextInt(adornos.size());
```

El problema es que si el `size()` de adornos es muy pequeño, por ejemplo 1, el único valor que te va a devolver es 0 (el 1 esta excluido).

Si por ejemplo fueran 2 adornos, te devolvería 0 y 1, y si no has hecho las suficientes pruebas puede hacerte creer que siempre te devuelve el mismo resultado.

Te dejo información de como funciona que quizás te ayude:
[random .nextInt(n)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/random_nextint_inc_exc.htm)

Answer (score 1):

De **java 1.7** en adelante puedes utilizar,

```
int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, adornos.size()+ 1);
```

`ThreadLocalRandom` pertenece al paquete `java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;`

Para versiones anteriores a **java 1.7**

```
int randomNum = new Random().nextInt((adornos.size() - 0) + 1) + 0;
```

Extraído de este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java)

Comment: Call required API 21

Answer (score 1):

Tu `Random` no parece tener ningún problema, posiblemente sea casualidad que siempre te esté saliendo el mismo. Cada vez que llames al método `getBmp` se generará un nuevo `Random`:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int max = 10; //Número máximo aleatorio que puede salir
int min = 1; //Número mínimo aleatorio que puede salir
int aleatorio = rnd.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
```

Answer (score 0):

> El problema es que el valor del random es siempre el mismo

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int random = rnd.nextInt(adornos.size());
```

**La única explicación es que el valor de la medida del array adornos sea 1, por esta razón se obtiene siempre un valor.**

Puedes realizar una prueba por ejemplo si defines que el valor de adornos.size() es 10 e imprimes el valor, obtendras numeros aleatorios de 0 a 9:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
for(int i =0; i< 100;i++) {
    int random = rnd.nextInt(10);
    Log.i(TAG, "valor random: " +  random);
}
```